# Converting video from 60 FPS to 25 FPS without slowing it

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I am trying to encode video through `ffmpeg` in Linux system. Original video has 60 FPS and I need to change it to 25, but when I do so, video is slower than original.

When I change it to 30, everything is fine (I guess it's easier for encodder to play every second frame than compute it to 25). How can I achieve that video will have 25 FPS with same speed as original video?

Currently I am using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i "test.mkv" -r 30 -vcodec libx264 -x264-params keyint=10:scenecut=0 -an -bsf:v dump_extra -video_size hd720 test2.mp4
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How are you checking output playback speed?

Comment: @Gyan I don't I guess, sorry, I work with ffmpeg for first time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does "video is slower than original" mean?
I try this:

```
ffmpeg -i BQTerrace_1920x1080_60.mp4 -r 25 -vcodec libx264 -x264-params keyint=10:scenecut=0 -an -bsf:v dump_extra BQTerrace_1920x1080_25.mp4
```

The output video isn't slower than original video, but it looks more unsmoother than original video. This is because that the output video has less frames than original video per second.

In my case, the total frames, frame rate, and video time are:

```
BQTerrace_1920x1080_60.mp4: 600 frames, 60 fps, 10s 
BQTerrace_1920x1080_25.mp4: 250 frames, 25 fps, 10s
```